# Remove folder specified by user at install time in Inno Setup Uninstaller

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

I have a setup script which allows the user to specify a relative path where the application will save some files and folders. The path will be saved to a `config.ini` file. Till then everything works as expected.

Now I want the uninstaller to perform a removing of all content under the specified path. In my installer script I have a variable

```pascal
var DataPath : String;
```

which holds the path.

To perform the removing I added the following lines of code ([as mentioned on their website](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=uninstalldeletesection)) to my script:

```
[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: DataPath
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do this?

My `[INI]` sections look like the following:

```
[INI]
Filename: "{app}\config.ini"; Section: "connection = standard"; \
    Key: datapath; String: {code:GetDataPath}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{code:GetDataPath}` in the `[UninstallDelete]`, the same way you use it in the `[INI]` section:

```
[UninstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: {code:GetDataPath}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the clarification and your answer, but this doesn't work either. I've updated my question to show how the "INI" and "UninstallDelete" section looks like.

Comment: No sorry, I forgot to mention that GetDataPath just returns the variable DataPath. I think this will not work because of the ephemerability of the variables, am I right? Your previous solution was one step in the correct right direction, because I need to delete the path from the INI file.

Comment: On the contrary. Constants in all sections (including the `[UninstallDelete]`) are resolved on *install* time (as resolved entries are stored to `unins000.dat`). That's why my previous solution was not working, as it was reading an INI file that did not exist yet.